# Modification to pointers changed output

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying to make the following code more friendly to large input values for BALLOT_SIZE but ran into an issue.

```
void Dot_Product(int a[BALLOT_SIZE][BALLOT_SIZE], int output[BALLOT_SIZE]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < BALLOT_SIZE; i++) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < BALLOT_SIZE; j++) {
            total = total + a[i][j] * (BALLOT_SIZE - (j+1));
        }
        output[i] = total;
    }
}

void Tally_Borda(int Results[BALLOT_SIZE][BALLOT_SIZE], struct Ballot * Ballots[NUM_VOTERS]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VOTERS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BALLOT_SIZE; j++) {
            Results[j][Ballots[i]->votes[j]-1]++;
        }
    }
}

int Borda_Count(struct Ballot * Ballots[NUM_VOTERS]) {

    printf("\nBorda Count:\n");
    int Results[BALLOT_SIZE][BALLOT_SIZE] ={{0}};
    Tally_Borda(Results, Ballots);
    Print_First_Candidate(Results[0], BALLOT_SIZE);

    int DotResult[BALLOT_SIZE];
    Dot_Product(Results, DotResult);
    Print_Results(DotResult, BALLOT_SIZE);

    int finalResult = Argmax(DotResult, BALLOT_SIZE);
    printf("%d is the Borda Count winner\n", finalResult);
    return finalResult;
}
```

The structure of a Ballot is just a pointer to an array of ints that represents the votes.

```
struct Ballot {
    int *votes;
};
```

The important part is that this works as intended, though I will explain or post code for the helper functions (such as Argmax or Print_Results) if requested.  The following is how I modified these functions and somehow managed to break functionality. I changed a few things to pointers or double pointers and the code executes, but has very different results from the first version, which I have verified as correct. It seems like the trouble lies with Tally_Borda as the I print the results of the first row (candidate) of Results to see if they match and they don't.

```
void new_Dot_Product(int * a[BALLOT_SIZE], int output[BALLOT_SIZE]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < BALLOT_SIZE; i++) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < BALLOT_SIZE; j++) {
            total = total + a[i][j] * (BALLOT_SIZE - (j+1));
        }
        output[i] = total;
    }
}

void new_Tally_Borda(int *Results[BALLOT_SIZE], struct Ballot * Ballots[NUM_VOTERS]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VOTERS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BALLOT_SIZE; j++) {
            Results[j][Ballots[i]->votes[j]-1]++;
        }
    }
}

int new_Borda_Count(struct Ballot * Ballots[NUM_VOTERS]) {

    int ** Results = malloc(BALLOT_SIZE*sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < BALLOT_SIZE; i++) {
        Results[i] = calloc(1, BALLOT_SIZE);
    }

    new_Tally_Borda(Results, Ballots);
    Print_First_Candidate(Results[0], BALLOT_SIZE);

    int * DotResult = malloc(BALLOT_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    new_Dot_Product(Results, DotResult);
    Print_Results(DotResult, BALLOT_SIZE);

    int finalResult = Argmax(DotResult, BALLOT_SIZE);
    printf("%d is the Borda Count winner\n", finalResult);
    return finalResult;
}
```

What have I missed?

In the following example, the number of voters is 1000 and the ballot size is 15, so the original borda count is correct as the first candidate's received votes total to 1000.

Sample output:

```
new_Borda Count:
First Candidate:
Position 1: 50
Position 2: 56
Position 3: 64
Position 4: 75
Position 5: 137
Position 6: 142
Position 7: 142
Position 8: 143
Position 9: 190
Position 10: 201
Position 11: 196
Position 12: 204
Position 13: 281
Position 14: 267
Position 15: 267
Totals:
Candidate 1: 12176
Candidate 2: 19270
Candidate 3: 24010
Candidate 4: 26582
Candidate 5: 26043
Candidate 6: 26198
Candidate 7: 27427
Candidate 8: 26731
Candidate 9: 26693
Candidate 10: 26525
Candidate 11: 27081
Candidate 12: 26318
Candidate 13: 69270
Candidate 14: 444370
Candidate 15: 1242793
15 is the Borda Count winner

Borda Count:
Position 1: 50
Position 2: 56
Position 3: 64
Position 4: 75
Position 5: 70
Position 6: 64
Position 7: 73
Position 8: 77
Position 9: 72
Position 10: 79
Position 11: 63
Position 12: 65
Position 13: 55
Position 14: 59
Position 15: 78
Totals:
Candidate 1: 6863
Candidate 2: 7134
Candidate 3: 7045
Candidate 4: 7129
Candidate 5: 6711
Candidate 6: 6879
Candidate 7: 7069
Candidate 8: 6922
Candidate 9: 7100
Candidate 10: 7044
Candidate 11: 7153
Candidate 12: 6967
Candidate 13: 7027
Candidate 14: 6928
Candidate 15: 7029
11 is the Borda Count winner
```

Comment: There's too much code to easily make sense of what your doing (plus a lack of output "as it should be" versus output "as you currently have it").

Comment: That was exactly it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in `new_Borda_Count` doesn't make much sense to me:

```
        Results[i] = calloc(1, BALLOT_SIZE);
```

The first argument to `calloc` is the number of elements, the second the size of the element.

With that,

```
        Results[i] = calloc(BALLOT_SIZE, sizeof *Results[i]);
```

seems more sensible to me, given that `Results` in your first example code is a 2D array of `BALLOT_SIZE` x `BALLOT_SIZE`